# MobileFirst adapter is not deploying

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

When I try to deploy a MobileFirst adapter to the MobileFirst Development server, eclipse hangs with background process on 66%.
At the same time the following is shown in the console:

`[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
 [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0018I: The server configuration was not updated. No functional changes were detected.`
When I try to invoke any procedure, eclipse also hangs on 33%.
I tried to reinstall eclipse, ADT, and MobileFirst. Immediately after reinstalling everything works fine, but the issue happens again after some period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the available heap size for your Eclipse instance.
See the instructions provided at: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help. Nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried opening the Worklight Console, deleting the adapter in question, and then deploying it?

Comment: @KarlBishop I tried to do so. The adapter was shown in the Worklight Console. But after removing and attempt to redeploy the adapter my Eclipse hangs the same way as before. Some additional information: I noticed that my apps cannot be previewed in the Mobile Simulator after this issue with adapters even if I close and reopen Eclipse I get the following error on preview 
`Error 404: Could not find application HelloApp-android-1.0`
When I reinstall the platform and don't use adapters, the preview for apps works fine.

Comment: @KarlBishop Another note. The adapter cannot be built. In the Progress tab I have 66% bar and `Deploy adapter on Worklight Server: Starting build of adapter: SimpleHTTPAdapter` message. .adapter  file is not generated in the bin folder.

Comment: Is it a single adapter, or any adapter?  Otherwise, it sounds like something may be horribly corrupt within your eclipse workspace.   Try exporting the project, creating a new workspace and importing the project, and try again. Or better yet, try a new workspace, create a new project/app/adapter, and see if that works.  I'm at a loss for more ideas.

Comment: This is happening to me now, on MFP 7.0.0. Creating a new workspace and importing the project does not fix it.