# VPN interferes with mobilefirst adapter deployment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a problem that has similar symptoms to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478797/mobilefirst-adapter-is-not-deploying) where adapter deployment hangs at 66% complete. As I'm not sure it's the same problem I'm starting this new question.

Using MFP 7.0.0, freshly installed on a new instance of Eclipse Luna.

I have a SQL Adapter that normally can be deployed with no difficulty, and these days if one edits the source that deployment occurs automatically.

As it happens I want to use a database only accessible via a VPN. So initially I developed some SQL scripts in the Database perspective. Using a JDBC URL of this form:

```
jdbc:db2://the.vpn.host:60006/STUDENT
```

My scripts work just fine. Now with the VPN still active I attempt to modify my SQL adapter to use that URL, automatic deployment kicks in and bingo, we get to the

> Deploy Mobile First adapter (66%)

stage and nothing further happens, ever, this is not just a few minutes time-out, it will sit there for hours. As soon as I drop the VPN the deployment completes.

So my question is two-fold:

1). It seems clear that some aspect of the adapter deployment code is not resilient to network issue - it's clearly not acceptable to hang indefinitely. I speculate that this may hint at the underlying cause of the referenced question.

2). There must be some network peculiarity here. I assume that the deployment process is having trouble reaching the server when the VPN is active. How can I diagnose this?

Comment: Add trace logs to the development server, also inspect Wireshark at the time of hang. Maybe these will reveal new information.

Comment: You could also provide thread dumps of the server and studio during the hang to be inspected. To perform a thread dump it is possible to use the jvisualvm tool which comes with every JDK.

Comment: anything about the above?

Comment: Sorry, no. Hitting a deadline, have had to work round this problem by working entirely locally, no VPN. Will get back to it when current project finished.

Comment: Some systems default to IPV6 lookups.  Can you try an experiment?  Can you put the following lines in your /etc/hosts file?  (Sorry, can't format in a comment)  "127.0.0.1 yourhostname" and "::1 yourhostname"

Answer (score 0):

We have recently identified and corrected the following via an APAR:
PI42968 ADAPTER/APPLICATION DEPLOYMENT TIME CAN BE EXTREMELY SLOW

The fix is now available via [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=7.0.0.0&platform=Mac%20OSX&function=fixId&fixids=7.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201506231917&includeRequisites=0&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http), so I'd like you to try this fix as I am hopeful it will help in your scenario as well.

Comment: Hi Idan, I'm using v 6.3 (October update) and I'm still having this issue. Any advise ?